# Tem como escrever todos os parágrafos que o usuário colocou só depois do laço em sequência? e de forma justificada?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tem como escrever todos os parágrafos que o usuário colocou só depois do laço em sequência? e de forma justificada?

```
import textwrap

numero_paragrafos = int(input('Quantos parágrafos tem o texto?\n'))

for c in range(1, numero_paragrafos +1):
    paragrafo = str(input(f'\n parágrafo {c}: \n'))
    print(textwrap.fill(paragrafo, width=40))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você fez duas perguntas em uma.

> Tem como escrever todos os parágrafos que o usuário colocou só depois do laço em sequência?

Pelo que entendi, você só quer escrever depois que o laço terminar, então, você precisa usar uma variável para armazenar o resultado:

```
paragrafos = [] # lista para armazenar os paragrafos lidos
for c in range(1, numero_paragrafos +1):
    paragrafo = str(input(f'\n parágrafo {c}: \n'))
    paragrafos.append(paragrafo)

# apos ler todos os paragrafos, imprima o resultado
for paragrafo in paragrafos:
    print(textwrap.fill(paragrafo, width=40))
```

> e de forma justificada?

Você pode usar essa função `justifica`, ela funciona como a `textwrap.wrap()` mas justifica o texto:

```
def justifica(texto, tamanho):
    for linha in textwrap.wrap(texto.replace('\n', ''), tamanho):
        por_palavra, sobra = divmod(tamanho - len(linha), linha.count(' '))
        por_palavra *= ' '; sobra *= [' ']
        yield ' '.join(palavra + por_palavra + (sobra.pop() if sobra else '') 
            for palavra in linha.split(' ')).rstrip()
```

A forma que ela funciona é chamando o `textwrap.wrap()` e em seguida completando cada linha com espaços distribuídos até ela ficar com o tamanho solicitado:

Para usar no seu código, só colocá-la linha do print:

```
print('\n'.join(justifica(paragrafo, 40)))
```